# Unreachable statement instantiating an instance of a fragment class inside of fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment called ProfilePicBtn and Im trying to load it in my fragment class called HomeFragment. But when I try and instantiate an instance of ProfilePicBtn I get an error saying unreachable statement. Note Im trying to follow the developer docs [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html).

```
package com.example.adam.hilo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        Fragment profileBtnFragment = new ProfileBtnFragment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has an unconditional return statement before the line which allocates the new ProfileBtnFragment. So the second line is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Change order of statements of onCreateView() .

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        Fragment profileBtnFragment = new ProfileBtnFragment();
        return view ;
    }
}
```